# Creating HTML table based on values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html table that I want to read from and create a new table underneath it from reading the first table. The first table looks like this:

### ID | Value

100 | 3

200 | 2

400 | 7

100 | 4

and should output this

### ID | Total

100 | 7

200 | 2

400 | 7

I'm having trouble creating the new rows after the first row and adding them based on ID, heres what I  have so far

```
var id = document.getElementByID("total");
var td = document.createElement('td');
var eleName = document.getElementsByName('initValue');
var total = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < eleName.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(eleName[i].value);
}
td.textContent = total;
id.appendChild(td);
```

Right now its just adding all the values

The ID can only increase by 100 and can have more than just 100-400 and more entries. The inital table is made with php

original table html

```
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">100</td><td id="initValue" name="initValue">3</td></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">200</td><td id="initValue" name="initValue">2</td></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">400</td><td id="initValue"name="initValue">7</td></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">100</td><td id="initValue" name="initValue">4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can we see the original table HTML (not the PHP!) please? What is the "total" element?

Comment: I added the original html to question, var id = document.getElementByID("total"); is the total header on the new table, because I'm trying to add the total value under it, so the 7 under the total header

Comment: Can you change the ids to reflect the 300/400 etc. That would make differentiating the output cells/rows easier.

Comment: Parameter 'id' should be unique. Use 'class' instead 'id' for multiple tags.

Comment: You may add unique value of td#itin as id to each <tr>, then check first and second child value of it. If first child value is present, just update second child value.

Comment: The other problem is that you are looping through all elements and not checking the id column value. You probably want to create a dictionary with id/total pairs before building out your table.

Comment: " var id = document.getElementByID("total"); is the total header on the new table,"...does it exist yet when you call this code? Also really what I meant was, what kind of element is it? To create tds under it, it must be a tr. It's not clear. Have you got any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a few people have said in the comments an element's `ID`, `<el id="something">`, must be unique and there cannot be any duplicates of it on the page. If you want to "group" similar elements use a class.

For solving your problem, since the value of your ID is is a direct sibling we only need one selector to get the ID and Value:

`const itin = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itin"]');`

With this we can loop over every ID element, `name="itin"`, and get the value with `el.nextElementSibling.textContent`. We're going to be keeping track of our IDs and Values in an object since javascript doesn't have key/value pair arrays: `let values = {}`.

We use `.nextElementSibling` to ignore white spaces and only get the next element.

We check if `values` already has a record of our ID with `hasOwnProperty`, if it does, we add the values together, if not we create a property in `values` with our ID and give it a value:

```
if (values.hasOwnProperty(inner)) {
  values[inner] = values[inner] += parseInt(next);
} else {
  values[inner] = parseInt(next);
}
```

Next we create a second loop to iterate over all properties in `values` and build our new table with that and the rest is pretty straight forward.

The two loops could likely be combined into one with a bit more logic to search for matching IDs.

```js
const itin = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itin"]');
let values = {};

itin.forEach(item => {
  const inner = item.textContent;
  let next = null;
  /* For direct sibling use this */
  //const next = item.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  
  /* For an unknown sibling use this */
  for ( let a = 0; a < item.parentElement.children.length; a++ ) {
    const n = item.parentElement.children[a];
    if ( n.getAttribute('name') === 'initValue') {
      next = n;
    }
  }
  next = next.textContent;
  /****/
  if (values.hasOwnProperty(inner)) {
    values[inner] = values[inner] += parseInt(next);
  } else {
    values[inner] = parseInt(next);
  }
});

const table_two = document.querySelector('.table-two tbody');

for (let prop in values) {
  const val = values[prop];
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let td1 = document.createElement('td');
  let td2 = document.createElement('td');
  td1.innerHTML = prop;
  td2.innerHTML = val;
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  table_two.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="itin">100</td>
    <td name="initValue">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="itin">200</td>
    <td name="initValue">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="itin">400</td>
    <td name="initValue">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="itin">100</td>
    <td name="initValue">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-two">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if they werent direct siblings, some more tds in between, how would you handle that?

Comment: @qaakmnd sorry for the late reply I have been on vacation. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An entirely javascript solution based on what you have provided is available on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bztr65ge/40/)

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByName("itin"); 
var tdDict = {};
var keys = [];
for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
 var tdId = tds[i];
  var tdVal = tds[i].nextSibling;
  if(tdId.textContent in tdDict){
    var curTotal = tdDict[tdId.textContent];
     var newTotal = curTotal + parseInt(tdVal.textContent);
     tdDict[tdId.textContent] = newTotal;
  }
  else{
   tdDict[tdId.textContent] = parseInt(tdVal.textContent);
     keys.push(tdId.textContent);
  }
}
var totalDiv = document.getElementById("totals");
var totalTable = document.createElement("table");
totalDiv.append(totalTable);
var hrow = document.createElement("tr");
var idHeader = document.createElement("th");
idHeader.textContent = "ID";
var totalHeader = document.createElement("th");
totalHeader.textContent = "Total";
totalTable.append(hrow);
hrow.append(idHeader);
hrow.append(totalHeader);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length; i++){
  var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    
  var idVal = keys[i];
    var valVal = tdDict[idVal];
    var idValTd = document.createElement("td");
    idValTd.textContent = idVal;
    var valValTd = document.createElement("td");
    valValTd.textContent = valVal;
    newRow.appendChild(idValTd);
    newRow.appendChild(valValTd);
    totalTable.appendChild(newRow); 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">100</td><td id="initValue" name="initValue">3</td></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">200</td><td id="initValue" name="initValue">2</td></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">400</td><td id="initValue"name="initValue">7</td></tr>
<tr><td name="itin" id="itin">100</td><td id="initValue" name="initValue">4</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="totals">

</div>
```